# OpenCV- Cant access element of Mat (of descriptors)

Tags: opencv, mat

I'm writing a simple program that extracts descriptors from images and writes them to files.

I'm saving the descriptors in a Mat variable, but I'm getting wrong values when trying to access them.

Here is the code:

```
        string s = format("%s\\%s\\img%d.ppm", dataset_dir.c_str(), dsname, k);
        Mat imgK = imread(s, 0);
        if( imgK.empty() )
            break;

        detector->detect(imgK, kp);
        descriptor->compute(imgK, kp, desc);

        //writing the descriptors to a file
        char fileName[512];
        sprintf(fileName,"C:\\BinaryDescriptors\\OpenCVRes\\%s\\%s\\Descriptors%d.txt",descriptor_name,dsname,k);
        FILE * fid;
        fid=fopen(fileName,"a+");
        for (int ix=0; ix< kp.size(); ix++){

            fprintf(fid,"%f \t%f", kp[ix].pt.x,kp[ix].pt.y);
            fprintf(fid, "\t1 \t0 \t1");
            fflush(fid);
            //writing the descriptor
            for (int jx=0;jx<desc.cols;jx++){
                int gil = desc.at<int>(ix,jx);
                printf("AAAA %d", gil);
                fprintf(fid,"\t%d",desc.at<int>(ix,jx));
                fflush(fid);
            }
        }
        fprintf(fid,"\n");
        fclose(fid);
```

The line where I'm accessing the descriptors matrix is int gil = desc.at int(ix,jx); Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, as I'm quite stuck :)

Thanks,

Gil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing the descriptor matrix with `int`, so that the matrix must be of type `CV_32SC1`. Are you sure it is that type? Most of the descriptors are coded with `float` (CV_32F) or `unsigned char` (CV_8U). Check that `desc.type() == CV_32SC1`.

By the way, you should use `cv::FileStorage` to save and load descriptors, it is much easier than directly accessing files.